# jQuery unterminated string literal

Tags: jquery

I am getting an unterminated string literal error, I understand this is probably to do with the PHP code in my script but I cannot understand what..

Here is what I have:

```
jQuery('#update-<?php echo $row->id; ?>').live('click', function (){

    var myname = "<?php $_POST['name_two'] ?>";
    var mystep = "<?php $_POST['step_two'] ?>";

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "postData.php",
        data: {name_two:myname, step_two:mystep},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
    });
});
```

The Error is on this line:

```
var myname = "<?php $_POST['name_two'] ?>";
```

Thanks
Rick

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `echo` here as well as removing double quotes if unnecessary here:

```
var myname = <?php echo $_POST['name_two'] ?>;
var mystep = <?php echo $_POST['step_two'] ?>;
```

Comment: Also mention that `$_POST['name_two']` and other vars can contian quotes `"`

Comment: it is definitely not to do with echo tried and still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the error was but I was sure it was a PHP error, so I decided that getting the values in jQuery would be better anyway..

```
var myname = jQuery('input[name="name_two"]').val();
var mystep = jQuery('#step<?php echo $row->id; ?> option:selected').val();
```